# Como restaurar um backup do banco de dados a partir de uma aplicação em c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho pesquisado como fazer a restauração de um backup do `BD` através de uma aplicação em c#, mas tive dificuldades em compreender a lógica. Já tenho programado um formulário que realiza o backup e não tenho e ideia de como funcionaria um de restauração, por exemplo, como eu faria para selecionar o arquivo de backup?

Segue o código que uso para realizar o backup se ajudar de alguma forma.

```
    private void FrmBackup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtServidor.Text = "USER-PC";
        txtDB.Text = "DBClinica_TCC";

    }

    private void btnSqlComand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection LCN = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand LCom = new SqlCommand();
        string LStrSql = "";
        //String de Conexão deve ser substituída pela do seu Servidor
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder Lstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        Lstr.DataSource = txtServidor.Text;
        Lstr.InitialCatalog = txtDB.Text;
        if(rbtSql.Checked == true)
        {
            Lstr.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Lstr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        }
        Lstr.UserID = txtLoginBD.Text;
        Lstr.Password = txtSenhaBD.Text;

LCN.ConnectionString = Lstr.ToString();
try
{
    //Abrindo a conexão
    LCN.Open();
    LCom.Connection = LCN; 
    DateTime d=DateTime.Now;
    //Criando o Comando que será executado para gerar o Backup       

    LStrSql = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + txtDB.Text + "] TO DISK='" + txtArquivo.Text +d.Day.ToString()+d.Month.ToString()+ "' WITH COPY_ONLY";
    LCom.CommandText = LStrSql;
    LCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    LCN.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Backup Gerado com Sucesso");

    Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\Backup
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Houve um erro ao tentar executar o Backup: "+ex.Message);
    LCN.Close();
}
```

codigo utilizado parar restaurar:
uso um `OpenFileDialog para pegar o arquvo de backup`

```
private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ofdRest.Multiselect = false;
        this.ofdRest.Title = "Selecionar Backup";
        ofdRest.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup";
        ofdRest.CheckFileExists = true;
        ofdRest.CheckPathExists = true;

        DialogResult dr = this.ofdRest.ShowDialog();

        if(dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach(String arquivo in ofdRest.FileNames)
            {
                txtArquivo.Text += arquivo;
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder Lstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
         Lstr.DataSource = txtServidor.Text;
        Lstr.InitialCatalog = txtDB.Text;
        if (rbtSql.Checked == true)
        {
            Lstr.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Lstr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        }
        Lstr.UserID = txtLoginBD.Text;
        Lstr.Password = txtSenhaBD.Text;
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(Lstr.ToString());

        try
        {
            cs.Open();
            String sqlquery = "Use Master ALTER DATABASE [" + txtDB.Text + "] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE RESTORE DATABASE [" + txtDB.Text + "] FROM DISK ='" + ofdRest.FileName + "' ALTER DATABASE [" + txtDB.Text + "] SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cs);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("restore complete");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Mas a dúvida é só como é que faz para escolher o ficheiro? Se for isso, basta usar um OpenFileDialog. Experimente o seguinte: OpenFileDialog ofd= new OpenFileDialog(); ofd.ShowDialog();

Comment: Na realidade queria saber como faz a restauração no geral, a questão de selecionar o ficheiro é uma das duvidas, mas obrigado!

Comment: Não vou postar uma resposta pois estou sem tempo e nunca usei essa solução, mas já vi a utilização de backup/restore com a biblioteca SMO da Microsoft. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx É uma solução mais robusta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado no que fez para o backup, fazer o mesmo para o restore. O único cuidado é que para fazer o restore, todas as conexões têm de ser desligadas.

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        try
        {
            cs.Open();
            String sqlquery = "Use Master ALTER DATABASE databasename SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE RESTORE DATABASE databasename FROM DISK ='" + txtRestoreFileLoc.Text + "' ALTER DATABASE databasename SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cs);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("restore complete");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

Comment: Oque seria o strConnString? em `SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(strConnString);`

Comment: strConnString == Lstr.ToString(); ....

Comment: É o teu connectionStringbuilder:SqlConnectionStringBuilder Lstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
Lstr.DataSource = @"USER-PC";
Lstr.InitialCatalog = "DBClinica_TCC";
Lstr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
Lstr.UserID = "usuario";
Lstr.Password = "senha";

LCN.ConnectionString = Lstr.ToString();

Comment: o código, aparenta estar funcionando bem, mas acabo recebendo esta mensagem de erro: [http://i.imgur.com/0Tm7l27.png] sabe me dizer oque é?

Comment: olhe o caminho e o nome do ficheiro. Alguma coisa está errada no objecto que está a enviar para definir o caminho para o ficheiro. Coloque o código que está a fazer agora.

Comment: vou alterar a pergunta o por lá, aqui não cabe mais.

Comment: utilizei um open file dialog para pegar o arquivo

Answer (score 2):

Há diversas formas de se fazer isso.

Sugiro que crie um serviço para executar o comando, que ao ser disparado, encerra todas as conexões ao banco e executa o comando.

O comando para ser executado seria o seguinte:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak'  
   WITH FILE = 6  
      NORECOVERY;  
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.bak'  
   WITH FILE = 9  
      RECOVERY;
```

Usando o valor **FILE = 6** quando for fazer um Full Restore e o valor **FILE = 9** quando for uma restauração parcial

Você encontra detalhes [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/88861)

Comment: Atendendo a sugestão, editei a resposta de forma a atender os requisitos e padrões.